# Angular AoT angular compiler cli vs angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, aot, angular-compiler-cli

what is the difference between this guide https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler that use `@angular/compiler-cli` and using command `ng build --prod (that use options --aot)`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Angular CLI takes care of more than just compiling your files for AOT.

Along with the AOT compilation, using `ng build -prod` will also minify, uglify, (partially) eliminate dead code, and bundle your application appropriately (including lazy loaded bundles).

Side note:

You can also use the `--build-optimizer` flag to further optimize your code. It will remove the vendor bundle, but your overall bundle size *should* be smaller. This flag is experimental right now and will eventually (hopefully) be moved into the `-prod` flag. One of the noticeable reasons it's not is that it makes compilation longer.